# Assigning a javascript object with and object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am just curious about this.

Let's say I have an array of objects and I create 1 object, lets name the array of objects *items* and the object *item*.

I want to get a particular item in my array of items by using the following code:

```
//gets an item base on ID
function get_item(td){
    var item = undefined;
    $.each(items, function(i, val) {
        if(val.item_id == td){
            item = val;
        }   
    });
    return item;
}
```

The get_item() basically gets an object matched with the supplied id.

So my question is this. What if I changed the properties of item will it also changed the properties of an object associated with it within the array?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you post sample array object?

Comment: show more code. Right after your "let's say I have...", show the code that you think corresponds to that situation.

Comment: ok i will edit my question.

Comment: if you are changing in item with reference to the array then the item will change.

Comment: If you are returning the same instance as stored in the array... yes it will

Comment: @JCFrane in this format yes it will change

Comment: Ok sir. Thanks. My confusion has now been reduced. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What if I changed the properties of item will it also changed the properties of an object associated with it within the array?

Yes.

Objects are not copied. Instead, references to the objects are passed around. Simplest example:

```
var a = [];
var b = a;
b.push(1);
console.log(a); // logs [1]
```

Many object-oriented programming languages work like this.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the object inside the array will also change because it's a reference. If you want more information I highly recommend reading [Objects and Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md#contents).

If you don't want it to change then you should use something like lodash's `_.clone()` function.

Also you could use filter to get the object:

```
function get_item(td){
    return items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.id === td;
    })[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update you function to:

```
var data= array();
function get_item(propertyValue, propertyName){
    var retval;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
         if(data[i][propertyName]==propertyValue){
            retval = data[i];
            break;
         }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Use it

```
var item1 = get_item(1,"id");
var item2 = get_item("john","name");
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? *"What if I changed the properties of item will it also changed the properties of an object associated with it within the array?"*

Comment: It does not answer, but it helps.

Comment: @JCFrane: There are many things that help. That doesn't mean that it is appropriate to post about them. As the term already implies, "answers" should *answer* the question that was posed. As the term implies, "answers" should *answer* the question that was posed.